# Dropwizard 0.7.1 vs 0.6.2: different YML configuration parser?

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, dropwizard

I've this .yml file:

```
template: Hello, testapp!
storage:
  storageUri: ****************
  storageAccessKey: ****************
  storageSecretKey: *******************
  buckets:
    "one": one-buck-name
    "second": second-buck-name
  buckets:
    - tag: one
      name: one-buck-name
    - tag: second
      name: second-buck-name
  one:
    bucket: one-buck-name
  second:
    bucket: second-buck-name
```

Below "storageSecretKey" I've three different ways to define the configuration for my buckets.
So I've many problems to parse this configurations with java.

For first configuration, I've used:

> ```
> @NotNull
> private ImmutableMap<String, String> buckets = ImmutableMap.of();
> ```

with this error:

```
 testapp.yml has an error:   * Unrecognized field at: storage.buckets
     Did you mean?:
       - storageUri
       - storageAccessKey
       - storageSecretKey
```

With second configuration (only that works):

@Valid
@NotNull
private List buckets = Lists.newArrayList();
public static class Bucket {

```
@Valid
@NotNull
@JsonProperty
private String tag;

@Valid
@NotNull
@JsonProperty
private String name;

public Bucket(){}

public String getTag() {
    return tag;
}

public void setTag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Finally, for third configuration:

```
@Valid
@NotNull
@JsonProperty
private One one;
@Valid
@NotNull
@JsonProperty
private Second second;

public class One {

   @Valid
   @NotNull
   @JsonProperty
   private String bucket;

   public String getBucket() {
      return bucket;
   }
}

public class Second {

   @Valid
   @NotNull
   @JsonProperty
   private String bucket;

   public String getBucket() {
      return bucket;
   }
```

}

With this error:

```
testapp.yml has an error:
  * Failed to parse configuration at: storage.one.bucket; Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of END_OBJECT token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.testapp.configurations.AppConfiguration["storage"]->com.testapp.configurations.StorageConfiguration["chat"]->com.testapp.configurations.One["one"])
```

Note: The third configuration works perfectly with dropwizard 0.6.2.

Latest info:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Where is the correct way to parse this damn storage configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle it is probably like your second example. You can do something simple like this (Note that in my .yml file I have `buckets` at the root -- just for example purposes).

example.yml

```
buckets:
  - name: name1
    properties:
      prop1: moo
      prop2: meep
      prop3: momp
  - name: name2
    properties:
      prop1: axe
      prop2: farid
      prop3: tom
```

SampleConfiguration.java

```
public class SampleConfiguration extends Configuration
{
  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty
  public List<Bucket> buckets;

  public static class Bucket {
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty
    private Map<String, String> properties;

    public String getBucketName() {
      return this.name;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
      return this.properties;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, your third one works for me if

```
one:
  bucket: one-buck-name
second:
  bucket: second-buck-name
```

is at the root level. If you're using the `storage:`, make sure to put all this nested inside your Storage POJO.